# List Index out of range, OpenCV, cv2.putText

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2

thres = 0.45  # Threshold to detect object

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)
cap.set(10, 70)

classNames = []
classFile = 'coco.names'
with open(classFile, 'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('n').split('n')

configPath = 'C:/Users/LENOVO/Jyputer_notebooks/OpenCV/Object_Detection_Files/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = 'C:/Users/LENOVO/Jyputer_notebooks/OpenCV/Object_Detection_Files/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)

net.setInputSize(320, 320)
net.setInputScale(1.0 / 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=thres)
    print(classIds, bbox)

    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
            cv2.rectangle(img, box, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
            cv2.putText(img, classNames[classId-1], (box[0]+10,box[1]+30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,2,(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.putText(img, str(round(confidence * 100, 2)), (box[0] + 200, box[1] + 30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Output', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I am confused what is the error in line 35.
Error:

> File
> "C:/Users/LENOVO/Jyputer_notebooks/OpenCV/Object_Detection_Files/ok.py",
> line 35, in 
> cv2.putText(img, classNames[classId-1], (box[0],box[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,2,(0,255,0),2) IndexError: list index out of
> range

Comment: Add some description to your question. You just brought code and error,

Comment: scratch that. it's an IndexError, so you gotta look at where you *index* things. `classNames`, `classId`, `box`. look at those variables. pure python issue. not related to OpenCV.